# What thread which Android use when fragment recreate from scratch?

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have a **ViewPager**.When some data changed,i set the adapter for the ViewPager again by call **ViewPager.setAdapter(new Adapter)**.What i wonder is,the Fragment is re-create (it jump on **onDestroyView** and then **onCreateView**) and my **Edittext** cannot set again the text.And if i remove all Fragment from FragmentTransaction and then setAdapter,the Fragment create a new one -> my Edittext set the text well.So is Fragment recreate itselft NOT from UI thread? ( Because i try the edditext.post and my edditext from first scenario work).Here is the code

Adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final ArrayList<Fragment> fmAct;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, ArrayList<Fragment> fm) {
    super(supportFragmentManager);
    fmAct = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fmAct.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fmAct.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return ((PrFragment) getItem(position)).getFragmentName();
}
```

what i do when re-set the adapter

```
fm.clear();
    fragmentAttendanceCome = new FragmentAttendanceCome();
    fragmentAttendanceCome.setFragmentName(getString(R.string.title_attendance));
    fragmentAttendanceCome.setParentActivity(this);

    fragmentAssessment = new FragmentAssessment();
    fragmentAssessment.setFragmentName(getString(R.string.daily_evaluation));
    fragmentAssessment.setParentActivity(this);

    fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo();
    fragmentInfo.setParentActivity(this);
    fragmentInfo.setFragmentName(getString(R.string.title_infomation));


    fm.add(fragmentAttendanceCome);
    fm.add(fragmentAssessment);
    fm.add(fragmentInfo);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fm));
```

This is my fragment :

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textview.setText(data)
// i already Bind it but i lazy to copy it,everything work well
}
```

Comment: Somewhat dependant on the OS version.

Comment: @Shark i tryed alot of devices with difference OS,the edditext still not change.:D